# Start activity without context

Tags: android

I'm using a custom Exception Handler in my android app so that whenever the app crashes, its overridden method `uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)` is called. In that method, I want to start an activity which prompts the user to mail the error log to the developer.

But the problem is, I'm not getting any context to start the activity. I also tried passing the context of previous activity to that method but as the app is stopped after crashing, the context is also gone and hence the activity could not be started with it.

Here is my Application Class onCreate method

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                Intent i = new Intent(QuickTatkalApp.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

What I'm getting after this is whenever the app is crashing, only a blank white screen is shown in the app.

Comment: Try to use ApplicationContext and the Intent with NEW_TASK flag

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a silly query, but there's no such class like `ApplicationContext` nor `ApplicationController` Btw @RajshreeTiwari, I passed the context using `getApplicationContext()` only but that also is not working

Comment: @VishalAfre Please post your code :)

Comment: What you are trying to do is difficult to get right, given that the app is in an unstable state at the time of the crash. I *strongly* encourage you to use ACRA rather than create your own crash reporting framework.

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari posted the code

Comment: Two options u have if u didn't find a solution, first : http://www.acra.ch/ and second : https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash . Also I guess u can combine both for smooth crash reporting .

Comment: thanks a lot @SahdeepSingh.... This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try create a class with extends from `Application` as follow

```
public final class MyAppApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
                //start your activity here with Application#packageContext
                //just calling "this"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this. But the onCreate method of this class is never getting called

Comment: Put your block code that throw the uncaught excepetion. Please!

Comment: @VishalAfre: "But the onCreate method of this class is never getting called" -- you need to register the `Application` in the manifest via the `android:name` attribute on the `<application>` element. See [the documentation for `Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) and [the documentation for `android:name` on `<application>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#nm).

Comment: yeah later I recalled that I didn't mention it in my manifest. I added it, also posted my code. But I'm getting just a blank white screen now after the crash.